# Nhibernate restrictions within a projection

Tags: nhibernate

I have a query which looks for jobs where all the hours assigned have not been used by the assigned technician.

In SQL I can use a having clause to query against the sum.

```
SELECT J.Jobid, J.HoursAssigned, SUM(JT.HoursUsed)
FROM Job J
JOIN JobTechnician JT ON JT.JobId = J.JobId
GROUP BY J.Jobid, J.HoursAssigned
HAVING J.HoursAssigned <> SUM(JT.HoursUsed)
```

This results in a dataset of the following

```
JOBID | HOURSASSIGNED | HOURSUSED
-----------------------------------
660015 | 10 | 8
660016 | 20 | 18
660017 | 30 | 28
660018 | 40 | 38
```

I can recreate the query as a projection in Nhibernate but how do I then place the restriction that currently exists within the SQL having clause?

```
ICriteria criteria = base.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Job));
criteria.CreateAlias("Job.JobTechnicianList", "JobTechnician", JoinType.InnerJoin);

criteria.SetProjection(
    Projections.ProjectionList()
                            .Add(Projections.Property("Job.JobId", "JobId")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("Job.HoursAssigned", "HoursAssigned")
                            .Add(Projections.Sum("JobTechnician.HoursUsed"), "HoursUsed")
                            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Job.JobId"))
                            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Job.HoursAssigned"))
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I checked the behavior you want is not supported. For workaround and status of the problem see [HHH-1043](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1043).